# Is it OK to mix wire gauges when trying to reduce voltage drop over long lines?

Tags: electrical, voltage, gauge

I'm planning out an off-grid electrical system in which I'll have electricity going to an outbuilding from the inverter. The total distance one-way is around 200 feet.

I'm concerned about voltage drop. Normally this wouldn't be too bad of an issue because at 120V I could just increase the wire gauge. I'll have 37.5A running along each line for a total of two lines, adding up to 75A. According to [this](https://www.southwire.com/calculator-vdrop) voltage drop calculator if I went with 2/0 gauge wire and set a goal of no more than 3% voltage drop the round-trip maximum length of the circuit would be 440 feet meaning 220 feet in one direction would more than cover me.

The issue I am running into is that the inverter I'm planning to use doesn't allow more than 4 gauge wire coming out of the AC output. Thicker gauge wire simply won't fit into the holes.

So my question is, can I start off with 4 gauge wire, going into the inverter, and then as soon as I come out of the inverter, I bump it up to 2/0 gauge wire along the same line going the rest of the 200 feet all the way out to my outbuilding?

I've never mixed different gauge wires before, so I'm not sure if this is safe and whether it would work. The smaller gauge is more than sufficient to handle the amperage, going through the circuit, but would mixing them together yield the voltage reduction that I want?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No problem, the voltage drop per foot will be higher on the small wire, but a few inches or feet is insignificant.

But amperage on the wire doesn't double, #2 aluminum the whole distance would be much cheaper will result in  about [4% voltage drop](https://www.calculator.net/voltage-drop-calculator.html?necmaterial=aluminum&necwiresize=7&necconduit=pvc&necpf=0.85&material=copper&wiresize=0.4066&resistance=1.2&resistanceunit=okm&voltage=120&phase=ac&noofconductor=1&distance=220&distanceunit=feet&amperes=37.5&x=14&y=13&ctype=nec).

If the idea of aluminum freaks you out do some research on [AA-1300 and AA-8000 alloys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminum_building_wiring).

Comment: Great, thank you so much for confirming this would work!

Comment: One thing I wasn't sure about, what do you mean by "But amperage on the wire doesn't double"?

Comment: Voltage drop is a function of resistance per foot of the cable, 37A one direction 200 ft, then 37A 200 ft the other, the length of cable in the calculator addresses that.

Answer (score 2):

200' is just over the distance at which I even bother doing a voltage drop calc.

You're using the calculator incorrectly in several ways.  For instance you seem to be assuming it's a one-way calc; no, it's round trip.  Also, select aluminum and think about overriding 3%.  They're wire salesmen, remember.

First, get clear on [how 120/240V split-phase actually works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMmUoZh3Hq4).  A significant knowledge gap is the only way you possibly could have arrived at 2/0 wire as an answer.

Caught up? Good.

---

So... we wire "4-wire" hot, neutral, hot, ground in the type of feeder you are planning.  With 120V loads, you'll have some on each pole or leg.  The neutral wire carries only differential current, so we get to calculate voltage drop using 240V.

And like I say, the voltage calculator already figures for round-trip.  Let me guess at your setup and give you a number.  4 AWG wire is too small for 75A (it maxes out at 65A in 75C rated copper)... so the inverter can't possibly be 75A. I think you have a 9000W inverter with 37.5A at 240V and 2 poles and a neutral.

You can get away legally with #6AL (50A rated) but #6 is oddly overrated just due to the way rounding works in the table, and it's more prone to voltage drop.  At your 37.5A it'll have 4.5% drop.  No thanks.

You can go 4 AWG aluminum, and that works at 2.86%.

However, #2 aluminum, particularly 2-2-2-4 MH feeder is a pricing "sweet spot" due to its very widespread use in service wires. It's available in more insulation types than #4 or #1.  I would price #2.  Not least it'll give you headroom for if you expand later.  *We are talking aluminum, remember*.

If in conduit, you use #2 THHN or XHHW, and a #6Al or #8Cu ground.

---

Anyway, how to bump.

First,  you haven't said whether the inverter's output terminals are rated for 75C thermal or for aluminum wire.  If you don't know, you'll need to pigtail with a short run of #8 copper. You can use larger if cost is no object :) So now how do you splice copper to aluminum?

The price ceiling is a large enclosure sufficient for wire bending space, and Polaris connectors (at about $20 a pop).

Cheaper is simple "disconnects" such as for A/Cs or hot tubs.  You have to [shop carefully](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/65/656a213d-c68b-4595-8fe4-d81af530aa61.pdf) to match up the disconnect the the wire size - lots of them take up to #3 but are not rated to #2.  That's an argument in favor of #4 aluminum.  On these cheapest disconnects make sure they have terminals for neutral and ground.

A slightly more sophisticated "disconnect" simply has 2 spaces for a breaker. Install a 60-70A breaker that uses the large breaker frame and accepts large wires up to 1/0 typically.

I like the disconnects *because they provide the enclosure for you* and obviously the lugs are just included.

Comment: You're right! I don't know where I got the 75 A from I can't find it anywhere now. I watched the video, it's very informative. I worked a lot with DC before but not really much with AC so that was very helpful. Here's a link to the inverter specs if you're interested and you're right it's a 9000 watt inverter. https://www.solar-electric.com/lib/wind-sun/Sol-Ark-12K_Spec.pdf So in that case I am getting 18.75 A per 120 V wire? That doubles my maximum circuit distance, which is great! Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @diy_builder_470 9000/120 is where you got 75A.  It is 37.5A per 120V wire, so think 37.5 x 120 x 2 poles.  Or think 37.5 x 240.  Either way.  If you grok DC, this video nicely shows how the split-phase AC system works (actually Edison invented it for DC power!) It's mainly about how it breaks, but it shows how it works. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJvyb_WujZg